# Have new windows pop up in same workspace of the program that created them in the i3 windows manager

Tags: i3-window-manager

I'm using the i3 windows manager on Linux Mint. I'm using a program called Scid vs PC to run a tournament between various chess engines. When two engines are playing, the software displays two windows, one for each engine, which tell us how each engine analyzes the current position. When a game finishes the two windows close, and two new windows are opened for the new engines that will be playing. The problem is, the new analysis windows will open in the workspace I'm working in, not the workspace of Scid vs PC. Is there a way to change that behavior so the analysis windows always open in the Scid vs PC workspace?

Thanks